# why the reactive http headers return list when query by key

Tags: java, http

I am get the http header from `org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServerHttpRequest` in reactive http reqest using this code:

```
ServerHttpRequest request = exchange.getRequest();
HttpHeaders headers = request.getHeaders();
List<String> host = headers.get("Host");
```

what makes me confusing is that the header query by key return a List data structure. As far as I know, the header was a key value data structure, why did not return the String vaue directly when using key to query the header result?

Comment: HTTP request headers can be repeated, so the client can send multiple values with the same header name. That's the reason for this design, I suppose.

Comment: Http headers are KV pairs indeed, but there is no uniqueness by key. This design mirrors very closely the choices made in the servlet API. If you just want to first value for a header use [`getFirst`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/HttpHeaders.html#getFirst-java.lang.String-)

Comment: like `a:b` and `a:c`, the same key a and difference value b and c?@ernest_k